# To show a static html page in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to show an html file in my assets folder but in web view i am seeing white blank page. I got similar example from stackflow only.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final String mimeType="text/html";
    final String encoding="UTF-8";
    String htmlString="<html><body>";
    Document doc;
    WebView wv= new WebView(this);
    Elements link = null;


    setContentView(wv);
    try{
        InputStream in=getAssets().open("myweb.html");
        byte[] buffer= new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(buffer);
        in.close();
        wv.loadData(new String(buffer), mimeType, encoding);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("MyWebView", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I just able to got the html source but not the page.

Comment: I tried to do with jsoup also but didnt able to understand the things easily.

Comment: Before this will work, however, your application must have access to the Internet. To get Internet access, request the INTERNET permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can load the content of the web view using

```
// add a webview with id @+id/the_webwiev to your main.xml layout file
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.the_webview);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myweb.html");
```

Comment: i need to load url from /res/raw/map.html file

Comment: then you would have to read the file manually using InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_html_file); and then webview.loadData(htmlcontent, "text/html", null);

Answer (score 6):

Uhm, did you try following the WebView example from the official webpage? It's really simple.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

I followed that and had no trouble implementing a WebView. Your code looks overly complicated for something that is quite simple.

If your file is called pmi_help.html (and located in the /assets/ folder), you load it using:

```
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pmi_help.html");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, its working fine now i have another task if you could help me i want to set an image as background in web view.

Answer (score 4):

Put your html page in `asset > www`, then load:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index1.html");
```